# Wildfly not starting a deployable war file

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, war, wildfly

I have a Spring Boot application that uses Spring Integration to do some SFTP polling...

I am trying to follow this [guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html) to package a jar file and deploy it as a war file to a wildfly 8.2 application server. I am using a gradle plugin that only allows the deploy of war or ear files.

So in my attempt to have this done I run locally with embedded tomcat, and it works flawlessly, but when I test it remotely then the app is deployed but never started.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Stasher extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

private static Class<Stasher> applicationClass = Stasher.class;

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
         return application.sources(applicationClass);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("MAIN STARTED ***************************");
        SpringApplication.run(Stasher.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Logs from Wildfly 8.2**

```
19:12:35,347 INFO  [org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter] (MSC service thread 1-4) Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
19:12:35,352 INFO  [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-4) Starting beans in phase -2147483648
19:12:35,353 INFO  [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-4) Starting beans in phase 0
19:12:35,353 INFO  [org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer] (MSC service thread 1-4) Adding {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
19:12:35,353 INFO  [org.springframework.integration.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel] (MSC service thread 1-4) Channel 'Stasher-Default.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
19:12:35,353 INFO  [org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer] (MSC service thread 1-4) started _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger
19:12:35,359 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication] (MSC service thread 1-4) Started application in 1.695 seconds (JVM running for 11619.131)
19:12:35,361 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS017534: Registered web context: /Stasher
19:12:35,439 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) JBAS018559: Deployed "Stasher.war" (runtime-name : "Stasher.war")
```

Why is the main not starting when in Wildfly?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the extentions of **SpringBootServletInitializer**, my **main** and **co nfigure** methods and added this method instead. It now starts up.

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml");
    PollableChannel ftpChannel = context.getBean("ftpChannel", PollableChannel.class);
    Message<?> message = ftpChannel.receive();

    System.out.println("Received message: " + message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the `configure` method that's used when launching a Spring Boot app in an app server. The `main` method is only used when you launch the app as an executable archive using `java -jar`.